# Clickable area of buttons with touch-events bound to them follow the scroll. [Webapp, Phonegap(Cordova), jQuery]

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm involved in developing a webapp aimed at iOS 5 and Android >=2.2
using Phonegap (Cordova 1.6.0). During testing I got back results from
one of the testers running ICS on his Samsung Galaxy S2, saying that a
menu in the app was not working. Digging in to it i realize that, even
if it visually stays in place (fixed position bottom-menu), the actual
clickable areas of the buttons in questions follow the scroll. So if
you scroll the page "half a button-height" up, only the upper half of
the buttons in the menu at the bottom is clickable.
This error only appears using touch-events (works fine when using for
example the click-event) and in a webview, not in the native browser.
It also appears as this problem does not exist in the "vanilla" ICS
that the Nexus runs.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: It might be a bug in Android rendering engine. I have similar problem with fixed-positioned block in default Android browser. My solution is simple - use absolute positioning instead of fixed. But for you it's not really an option.

P.S. issue reproduced on Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (Android 4.0.1) and on Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1)

Comment: it's happen as well with absolute position though. i have footer buttons that is slide out of viewport but the clickable area is still there